# A way to call a method in most derived class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do you call a method in the most derived class of a ruby object?

For example, in Rails, one can have a controller that inherits from `ApplicationController`, or say, `Devise::RegistrationsController`. So, say I want the user to override some method in their controller, and call that override from the base class: What would be the best syntax for doing it?

Comment: What you have described is not the way in which inheritance works. Perhaps you could explain and ask how to accomplish your specific goal.

Comment: what I am asking is if there is anything like virtual inheritance on other languages? if `class B < A` and the code of `A::foo` wants to call `B::bar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing you need to do, method lookup always starts at the most-derived class. That is, after all, the whole point of overloading.

```
class A
  def foo
    bar
  end

  def bar
    :A
  end
end

class B < A
  def bar
    :B
  end
end

B.new.foo
# => :B
```

Comment: @diffeomorphism If this is the answer (which is perfectly fine) then the question is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use a method from, for example, UserController in lieu of the Devise RegistrationsController? Let me know what you are trying to accomplish specifically using code examples. :)

Comment: the actual reason I was trying to force a check on the inherited controller, this is the question with the original problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/33490887/1792701

Answer (score -1):

> what I am asking is if there is anything like virtual inheritance on other languages?

No, Ruby does not have this.